# asking a way to prove an inequality

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality, partial-differential-equations, global-analysis

Assume $\Omega$ is a bounded smooth domain in $\mathbb R^N $ with $N \ge 5 $ and $u \in C^2(\Omega)$ .
I want to proof

> $$\int_{\Omega}\frac{|\nabla u|^2}{|x|^2}d{x} \;\ge\; \left(\frac{N-4}{2}\right)^2 \int_{\Omega} \frac{|u|^2}{|x|^4} dx$$

I know that it is a special case of caffereli-kohn- nirenberg inequality, but I want a proof that it direct. Because i do not know the proof of mentioned inequality.

I will be thanksed if some one help me.

Comment: Have a look at http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/%28SICI%291097-0312%28199803%2951:3%3C241::AID-CPA2%3E3.0.CO;2-A/abstract